# PHP ZIP file download

Tags: php, zip, download

Here is a code which downloads attachment files from the an imap server. Almost all file types (pdf, doc, xls, etc) are being downloaded correctly, where as some zip files give the following error:

"The archive is either in unknown format or damaged"

Code:

```
//data from imap server
$name = "xyz 123.zip";
$type = "APPLICATION";
$subtype = "ZIP";
$encoding = "BASE64";
$body = imap_base64($data);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: '. $type .'/'. $subtype);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$name);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: '.$encoding);
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $body;
```

Also if I echo the data and convert it to a file using:

http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

The file is being downloaded correctly. Hence no problem in getting the file from server.
Where am I going wrong??

Comment: what i believe is that your zip file is not fully downloaded, so the unzipper program shows that kind of error

Comment: how can i verify that. i have tried to download it multiple times. also the size is same as that on the server. and it works if i print the encoded file and decode it manually.

Comment: the code you provide don't seem to be related to the error when unzip. check the part of code that performs downloading to get the $data

Comment: check the file size (exact size in bytes), and the checksum. if the file size in bytes of the downloaded file and the file size in bytes of the file on server are the same; then check the checksum (md5 or whatever); if even the checksums are the same => i believe that the original file on server is corrupted.

Comment: @Paul. My fault. The file downloaded is 0 bytes. But my variable '$body' is not null, so I think there is an issue in the "header" part of the code. Am I right??

Comment: since $data is a blank string or null, the value in $body is unsuable! check how $data is gotten from server.

Comment: got the culprit: 
$body = imap_base64($data);
'data' is not null, I checked, but when I try to decode it using imap_base64, it returns a null variable 'body'. Is there an alternative to imap_base64

Comment: the value of strlen($body) should be almost equal the real size of the zip file, if not: the value of $body may not be truely reliable. check the strlen($data) also, this value should be around double the real file size!

Comment: base64_decode does the trick. Thanks a lot @Paul.

Answer (score 6):

Script for downloading files in zip format:
**zip.php**

```
<?php

/**
* Zip file creation class.
* Makes zip files.
*
* Last Modification and Extension By :
*
*  Hasin Hayder
*  HomePage : www.hasinme.info
*  Email : countdraculla@gmail.com
*  IDE : PHP Designer 2005
*
*
* Originally Based on :
*
*  http://www.zend.com/codex.php?id=535&single=1
*  By Eric Mueller <eric@themepark.com>
*
*  http://www.zend.com/codex.php?id=470&single=1
*  by Denis125 <webmaster@atlant.ru>
*
*  a patch from Peter Listiak <mlady@users.sourceforge.net> for last modified
*  date and time of the compressed file
*
* Official ZIP file format: http://www.pkware.com/appnote.txt
*
* @access  public
*/
class zipfile
{
    /**
     * Array to store compressed data
     *
     * @var  array    $datasec
     */
    var $datasec      = array();

    /**
     * Central directory
     *
     * @var  array    $ctrl_dir
     */
    var $ctrl_dir     = array();

    /**
     * End of central directory record
     *
     * @var  string   $eof_ctrl_dir
     */
    var $eof_ctrl_dir = "\x50\x4b\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00";

    /**
     * Last offset position
     *
     * @var  integer  $old_offset
     */
    var $old_offset   = 0;


    /**
     * Converts an Unix timestamp to a four byte DOS date and time format (date
     * in high two bytes, time in low two bytes allowing magnitude comparison).
     *
     * @param  integer  the current Unix timestamp
     *
     * @return integer  the current date in a four byte DOS format
     *
     * @access private
     */
    function unix2DosTime($unixtime = 0) {
        $timearray = ($unixtime == 0) ? getdate() : getdate($unixtime);

        if ($timearray['year'] < 1980) {
            $timearray['year']    = 1980;
            $timearray['mon']     = 1;
            $timearray['mday']    = 1;
            $timearray['hours']   = 0;
            $timearray['minutes'] = 0;
            $timearray['seconds'] = 0;
        } // end if

        return (($timearray['year'] - 1980) << 25) | ($timearray['mon'] << 21) | ($timearray['mday'] << 16) |
                ($timearray['hours'] << 11) | ($timearray['minutes'] << 5) | ($timearray['seconds'] >> 1);
    } // end of the 'unix2DosTime()' method

    /**
     *
     * Function to force the download of the archive as soon as it is created
     *
     * @param archiveName string - name of the created archive file
     * @access public
     * @return ZipFile via Header
     */
    public function forceDownload($archiveName) {
        if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) {
            ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
        }

        // Security checks
        if( $archiveName == "" ) {
            echo "<html><title>Public Photo Directory - Download </title><body><BR><B>ERROR:</B> The download file was NOT SPECIFIED.</body></html>";
            exit;
        }
        elseif ( ! file_exists( $archiveName ) ) {
            echo "<html><title>Public Photo Directory - Download </title><body><BR><B>ERROR:</B> File not found.</body></html>";
            exit;
        }

        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private",false);
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($archiveName).";" );
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($archiveName));
        readfile("$archiveName");
    }

    /**
     * Adds "file" to archive
     *
     * @param  string   file contents
     * @param  string   name of the file in the archive (may contains the path)
     * @param  integer  the current timestamp
     *
     * @access public
     */
    function addFile($data, $name, $time = 0)
    {
        $name     = str_replace('\\', '/', $name);

        $dtime    = dechex($this->unix2DosTime($time));
        $hexdtime = '\x' . $dtime[6] . $dtime[7]
                  . '\x' . $dtime[4] . $dtime[5]
                  . '\x' . $dtime[2] . $dtime[3]
                  . '\x' . $dtime[0] . $dtime[1];
        eval('$hexdtime = "' . $hexdtime . '";');

        $fr   = "\x50\x4b\x03\x04";
        $fr   .= "\x14\x00";            // ver needed to extract
        $fr   .= "\x00\x00";            // gen purpose bit flag
        $fr   .= "\x08\x00";            // compression method
        $fr   .= $hexdtime;             // last mod time and date

        // "local file header" segment
        $unc_len = strlen($data);
        $crc     = crc32($data);
        $zdata   = gzcompress($data);
        $zdata   = substr(substr($zdata, 0, strlen($zdata) - 4), 2); // fix crc bug
        $c_len   = strlen($zdata);
        $fr      .= pack('V', $crc);             // crc32
        $fr      .= pack('V', $c_len);           // compressed filesize
        $fr      .= pack('V', $unc_len);         // uncompressed filesize
        $fr      .= pack('v', strlen($name));    // length of filename
        $fr      .= pack('v', 0);                // extra field length
        $fr      .= $name;

        // "file data" segment
        $fr .= $zdata;

        // "data descriptor" segment (optional but necessary if archive is not
        // served as file)
        $fr .= pack('V', $crc);                 // crc32
        $fr .= pack('V', $c_len);               // compressed filesize
        $fr .= pack('V', $unc_len);             // uncompressed filesize

        // add this entry to array
        $this -> datasec[] = $fr;

        // now add to central directory record
        $cdrec = "\x50\x4b\x01\x02";
        $cdrec .= "\x00\x00";                // version made by
        $cdrec .= "\x14\x00";                // version needed to extract
        $cdrec .= "\x00\x00";                // gen purpose bit flag
        $cdrec .= "\x08\x00";                // compression method
        $cdrec .= $hexdtime;                 // last mod time & date
        $cdrec .= pack('V', $crc);           // crc32
        $cdrec .= pack('V', $c_len);         // compressed filesize
        $cdrec .= pack('V', $unc_len);       // uncompressed filesize
        $cdrec .= pack('v', strlen($name) ); // length of filename
        $cdrec .= pack('v', 0 );             // extra field length
        $cdrec .= pack('v', 0 );             // file comment length
        $cdrec .= pack('v', 0 );             // disk number start
        $cdrec .= pack('v', 0 );             // internal file attributes
        $cdrec .= pack('V', 32 );            // external file attributes - 'archive' bit set

        $cdrec .= pack('V', $this -> old_offset ); // relative offset of local header
        $this -> old_offset += strlen($fr);

        $cdrec .= $name;

        // optional extra field, file comment goes here
        // save to central directory
        $this -> ctrl_dir[] = $cdrec;
    } // end of the 'addFile()' method


    /**
     * Dumps out file
     *
     * @return  string  the zipped file
     *
     * @access public
     */
    function file()
    {
        $data    = implode('', $this -> datasec);
        $ctrldir = implode('', $this -> ctrl_dir);

        return
            $data .
            $ctrldir .
            $this -> eof_ctrl_dir .
            pack('v', sizeof($this -> ctrl_dir)) .  // total # of entries "on this disk"
            pack('v', sizeof($this -> ctrl_dir)) .  // total # of entries overall
            pack('V', strlen($ctrldir)) .           // size of central dir
            pack('V', strlen($data)) .              // offset to start of central dir
            "\x00\x00";                             // .zip file comment length
    } // end of the 'file()' method


    /**
     * A Wrapper of original addFile Function
     *
     * Created By Hasin Hayder at 29th Jan, 1:29 AM
     *
     * @param array An Array of files with relative/absolute path to be added in Zip File
     *
     * @access public
     */
    function addFiles($files /*Only Pass Array*/)
    {
        foreach($files as $file)
        {
        if (is_file($file)) //directory check
        {
            $data = implode("",file($file));
                    $new_file = $this->prefix_name.end(explode('/', $file));
                    $this->addFile($data, $new_file);
                }
        }
    }

    /**
     * A Wrapper of original file Function
     *
     * Created By Hasin Hayder at 29th Jan, 1:29 AM
     *
     * @param string Output file name
     *
     * @access public
     */
    function output($file)
    {
        $fp=fopen($file,"w");
        fwrite($fp,$this->file());
        fclose($fp);
    }



} // end of the 'zipfile' class
?>
```

**Example usage:**

```
<?php

include_once('zip.php');

$zip_file = 'my_files.zip'; // name for downloaded zip file

$ziper = new zipfile();
$ziper->prefix_name = 'folder/'; // here you create folder which will contain downloaded files
$ziper->addFiles($files_to_zip);  // array of files
$ziper->output($zip_file); 
$ziper->forceDownload($zip_file);
@unlink($zip_file);

?>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I do not want to download multiple files as a zip file, rather I have a zip file on a server which needs to be downloaded. So the forceDownload function in your file is same as my code above.

Comment: Just remove the 'forceDownload' call.

Comment: In answer of CroiOS There should change in zip.php file at line 241 pass by varialbe for find last element of array $tempName = explode('/', $file); $new_file = $this->prefix_name.end($tempName); $this->addFile($data, $new_file); } For avoid error "Only variables should be passed by reference"

Comment: for me, doesn't work as expected; for creating zips these days, I suggest using ZipArchive object instead (see https://gist.github.com/somatonic/6427247)

Comment: or here's my updated gist: https://gist.github.com/YakovL/a5425e7f4e116aee87fb121a3ab0b26d

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little late but I faced the same problem and these lines worked like a charm for me

```
while (ob_get_level()) {
  ob_end_clean();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was imap_base64. It was not decoding the data correctly. I replaced it with base64_decode as follows and the code worked fine.

```
$body = base64_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close to the solution! I found the way to solve this was to remove the Content-type header all together and let the browser figure out that this was a .zip file. Remove the Content-Type and it should work as needed.

```
// Remove this line 
header('Content-Type: '. $type .'/'. $subtype);
```

In my console (Chrome) I was receiving a strange message(s) saying:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream:
>
> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/zip:

When I removed the MIME Type (Content-type header) the .zip stopped giving me an error and worked normally.

The most basic download script for making the .zip to work looked like this at the end: (note: You can still add more headers for caching and such)

```
<?php
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$Filename."\"");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($Filename));
    readfile($Filename);
?>
```

**Edited**

Your .zip's will also run into problems if the browser is reading extra spaces. You can prevent the extra spaces at the end of the readfile() by adding exit(); but you'll want to make sure you don't have any spaces at the start of the file. This is particularly common when dealing with frameworks (especially your own). A little trick: If you include all the functions, configs and classes before your buffer starts outputting HTML, view your source code. At the start there will be a space before the .

Answer (score 0):

```
It Worked For Me. It Download My .Zip File. But, you have to provide the full path of File, where it is located.
For ex: My File is inside assets/upload Folder. Attach name of that file with this location. You will download it without any problem.

$FilePaths='assets/Upload/'.$FileName; //Give proper file path with file name.

download_file($FilePaths);

function download_file( $fullPath )
{
  if( headers_sent() )
    die('Headers Sent');


  if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');


  if( file_exists($fullPath) )
  {

    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

    switch ($ext) 
    {
      case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
      case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
      case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
      case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
      case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
      case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
      case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
      case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
      case "jpeg":
      case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
      default: $ctype="application/force-download";
    }

    header("Pragma: public"); 
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); 
    header("Content-Type: $ctype");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fullPath)."\";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile( $fullPath );

  } 
  else
    die('File Not Found');

}
```

For more info, Check this [File Download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329586/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-php-and-mysql-db/32330239#32330239)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anyone mention this yet, but try removing the Content-Length header when download ZIP files. I had this exact same problem and it worked for

Answer (score -1):

This is really good for big file download. User will be receiving file immediately. Maybe zip will be correct too this way.

```
    if(file_exists($filename) && is_readable($filename) && file_exists($filename)){
             header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename(str_replace(' ', '_', $filename)));
             header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
             header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
             header("Content-Type: application/download");
             header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
             header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
             flush(); // this doesn't really matter.

             $fp = fopen($filename, "r");
             while (!feof($fp))
             {
                 echo fread($fp, 65536);
                 flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
             }
             fclose($fp);
         exit;
    }
```

Comment: Multiple content types.