# Zip file downloads, but is invalid?

Tags: php, download

I use this code to enable users to download a zip file:

```
if(file_exists($filename)){
         header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename(str_replace(' ', '_', $filename)));
         header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
         header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
         header("Content-Type: application/download");
         header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
         header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
         flush();

         $fp = fopen($filename, "r");
         while (!feof($fp))
         {
             echo fread($fp, 65536);
             flush();
         }
         fclose($fp);
     exit;
}
```

When the file is downloaded, it only downloads 25,632 kilobytes of data. However the zip file is 26,252 kilobytes ...

Why does the browser get all 25MB but then stop?

I checked the `Content-Length` header to make sure it was correct and it is...

### edit

In firefox, when i download the file, it says 'of 25mb' SO the browser thinks that 25mb is the COMPLETE amount... however, the content-length when echo'd is 26252904?

Comment: 3 Different content types? This, IMO, is not valid.

Comment: I got this whole function off another question in stack overflow. and it was marked as valid and upvoted... So i'm the 3 content types arent an issue!

Comment: Can you put in the link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681844/php-zip-file-download

Answer (score 7):

add this before your code

```
ob_clean();
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation why this answers the question?

Comment: I was having this problem. try to zip some file on the fly and force to save it. i got this invalid file error. so i used that above code before my code and it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Your `header('Content-Type ...)` calls are useless as only the last one will be sent to the browser.

Downloads are triggered by `Content-Disposition: attachment`. You should send the actual `Content-Type: application/zip` if you are sending a zip file.

Finally, your read loop is unnecessary.

Putting it all together, your code should look like this:

```php
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $quoted_filename = basename(addcslashes($filename, "\0..\37\"\177"));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$quoted_filename}\"");
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename));
    readfile($filename);
}
```

Comment: Hello and thankyou for your answer. I tried it and it did not work!
It only downloads `1KB` of data?

Comment: What happens if you remove `content-length`? And are you sure there is not something wrong with your file?

Answer (score 0):

Use a single MIME type to represent the data.

In this case using `application/octet-stream` will do just fine. This is when you dont know the MIME before hand. When you know it, you must put it. Do not use multiple content-type headers.

Usually, when the browser doesn't know how to handle a particular MIME, it will trigger the download process. Further, using `Content-disposition: Attachment; ..` ensures it.

There exists a simple `readfile($filename)` which will send out the bytes of the file to the requesting process like below:

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=" . basename($filename);
readfile($filename);
```

Comment: I tried your response... My code was
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($filename));header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");readfile($filename);
But it only downloaded 1 byte of the data?

Comment: Did you forget the `content-length` header?

Comment: I did forget it... but i added it `header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));` and it only downloaded `1KB` In the RFC 2616 specification, it says `content-length` is in decimal number of OCTETs. What is this and does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Are you sure the $filename points to proper path? May be it emits a (suppressed) warning. Without download specific code, try: `echo filesize($filename)`

Comment: my filename is:
`$filename = "/home/www/sinnershighway.co.uk/media/Sinners-Highway-EP.zip";`
and `echo filesize($filename);` returns 26252904

Comment: @Alex: Can you try the code I put up there? Can you check if proper filesize gets sent across to  the browser (implying the file is accessible) ?

Comment: I tried your code myfriend... So far the only thing i've tried that got me > 1 KB is the original method i tried?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. The file downloaded fine in Firefox but not in IE. It appeared that Apache was gzipping the files and IE was not able to ungzip so the files were corrupted. The solution was to disable gzipping in Apache. You can also check if PHP is not gzipping on the fly and disable it too.
For Apache you can try:

```
SetEnv no-gzip 1
```

And for PHP, in .htaccess:

```
php_flag zlib.output_compression on
```

Comment: `php_flag zlib.output_compression on` gave me a 500: server error :(

Comment: sorry but, were do i put `SetEnv no-gzip 1` i'm on a semi-dedicated server and cannot acces apache i dont think

Comment: I tried `SetEnv no-gzip 1` but i got a 500 server error. im now trying `Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.zip$ - [E=no-gzip:1]`

Comment: If you can't access config files you can ask your server provider for help. Maybe even someone else had similar problem on their server and they know exact solution. Sorry, but can't be of any more help here.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is by No means a REAL ANSWER.

However i did get it to work... I just set the Content-Length to 30000000. Therefor it thinks the file is bigger than it actually is, and then it downloads it all.

Ugly hack i know, but i couldn't find ANY other way