# Node.js readFileSync ZIP file

Tags: node.js

I am trying to read a ZIP file and output it to the browser, get the code that's shown on the page and save it as a ZIP file

```
fs.readFileSync('/dir/file.zip','utf-8')
```

When I do this, I get output that starts with `PK�coG���^�*filename.txt` and goes on for a bit longer. When I save the resulting text as file.zip however, I can't extract the file. It says its corrupt or not a valid ZIP file.

If I open a very similar file I have in Notepad++, the start and ends are pretty similar. Am I missing something obvious?

Any ideas how to get the contents of the ZIP file, save it so I can extract it, only using the `fs.readFileSync` function?

Comment: Do you use pure node HTTP module, or you use some library like express?

Answer (score 0):

ZIP is a binary file type, when you output it in a browser as a text and copy-paste the text to a text editor, you won't get the same value as in the original file (likely web browser will interpret some of its contents as HTML tags, and/or a copy-paste will mangle some binary characters, and/or a text editor itself will mangle them).

What you should do is set appropriate HTTP response headers when serving the file to the browser, so that the browser *knows* it's a ZIP and can display the user a file download prompt. If you don't send any response headers, browser will just display contents as a text file which doesn't make sense.

Have a look at this question which has a PHP solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10817739/245966

Basically you need to set appropriate `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` header, and (optionally) `Content-Length`.

```
setResponseHeader('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.zip');
setResponseHeader('Content-Type: application/zip');
setResponseHeader('Content-Length: ' + fileLengthInBytes);
```

Replace `setResponseHeader` with appropriate call to your HTTP framework which sets the response header.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read a zip file as a character encoding (utf-8) which should probably be changed to 'binary'

Answer (score -1):

You need to use zlib module of nodejs for these purposes
https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib_createunzip_options

Comment: What if I don't have access to add new modules?

Comment: D'oh. The output to the screen using the code I have "looks promising" based on other ZIP files I've opened in notepad++