# .zip file downloading as .php

Tags: php, javascript, zip

I have a .zip file which is generated on the server using php. The file generated is valid and I checked it by downloading it via ftp etc.

I need to create a way for a user to download this file after it is generated and then the file is deleted. Here are the headers that I am sending.

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-type: application/zip'); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($archive_file_name).'"');
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($this->dirPath."/".$archive_file_name) );
ob_clean();
//echo is_file($this->dirPath."/".$archive_file_name);
readfile($this->dirPath."/".$archive_file_name);
unlink($this->dirPath."/".$archive_file_name);
exit;
```

The code above works when I try to download the first few times but after few turns it starts downloading as .php file instead of .zip

The file download is triggered by going to a specific link which starts the creation of zip file. Once it is done, it sends out the headers to begin the download

Comment: try this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681844/php-zip-file-download

Comment: "The code above works when I try to download the first few times" how many times ?? I downloaded more than 15 times and its working..how much for you ??

Comment: if user connection become disconnect php continue until finish work for that your file will be remove you download or not after one request you can use `connection_status()==0` for check connection like below see answer for more

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596116/caching-http-responses-when-they-are-dynamically-created-by-php/10596231#10596231

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code looks proper. However you need to ensure the preceding and succeeding spaces for your code.
while adding headers in your code, the space will disrupt and will not load the zip file.
Check once again and remove the spaces on top and bottom of page.

And a line which says 
readfile($this->dirPath."/".$archive_file_name);
can be removed from code

Comment: yeah.. space was the culprit.. was using multiple text editors for editing my files.. I think somewhere down the line an extra space got attached. Wasted a lot of time on this!

Answer (score 0):

try this header available you to download with resume 
i suggest use database or log file for understand  the file downloaded or not because this header available downloader to download part-part

get Request range from downloader you can use fseek to read range of file

```
$Range=@$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'];//Range: bytes=843530240-
$Cach="";
if($Range!=""){
  $Range=explode("=",$Range);
  $Cach=(int)trim($Range[1]," -");      
}
```

caching controller

```
function caching_include($file) {
     $headers = $_SERVER;
     // Get the modification timestamp
     if(!(list(,,,,,,,,,$lastModified) = @stat($file))){
           echo Error;
           exit();          
     }
     // Build our entity tag
     $eTag = "ci-".dechex(crc32($file.$lastModified));
     if (false and (strpos(@$headers['If-None-Match'], "$eTag")) &&(gmstrftime("%a, %d %b %Y %T %Z", $lastModified) == @$headers['If-Modified-Since'])) {
        // They already have an up to date copy so tell them
        header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
        header('Cache-Control: private');
        header("Pragma: ");
        header('Expires: ');
        header('Content-Type: ');
        header('ETag: "'.$eTag.'"');
        exit;
     } else {
       // We have to send them the whole page
        header('Cache-Control: private');
        header('Pragma: ');
        header('Expires: ');
        header('Last-Modified: '.gmstrftime("%a, %d %b %Y %T %Z",$lastModified));
        header('ETag: "'.$eTag.'"');
     }
  }
```

header for download

```
header("Server: SepidarSoft/ir-system");//server name 
header("Date: ".date("a,d b Y H:M:S GMT",time()));
header("X-Powered-By: SepidarSoft");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-disposition:filename=\"".$BaseName."\"");//file name
caching_include($FPatch);//caching controller 
header("Accept-Ranges:bytes");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n"); 
header("Connection: Keep-Alive");
header("Content-Type: $Type");//file type like application/zip
header("Content-Length: ".($FSize-$Cach)); //length of download it is for resume  
header("Content-Range: bytes ".$Cach."-".($FSize-1)."/".$FSize); //download range it is for resume
header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content",true);
set_time_limit(0);
```

if use `set_time_limit(0);` in code if user connection become disconnect php continue until finish work for that your file will be remove you download or not after one request you can use `connection_status()==0` for check connection  like below

```
$Speed=102400;
fseek($Handle,$From);//if use resume it is useful 
while(!@feof($Handle) and (connection_status()==0)){
    print(fread($Handle,$Speed));
    flush(); 
            ob_flush(); 
 } 
 if(connection_status()==0){//with this condition you can understand download is down by user 
       unlink($this->dirPath."/".$archive_file_name);
 }
```