# How can I force a file download in all browsers?

Tags: php

I am working on script which allows user to download pptx and zip files using php, but this script behaves different on different browsers. I tried many scripts available on the internet, but nothing worked properly so I made this one collecting chunks from different scripts.

1. firefox => works perfect
2. Opera   => Downloads file as a HTM file
3. Safari  => 0kb File
4. IE      => Catching old file

My Code:-

```
// content type for pptx file 
$ctype = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation";
$file = "http://www.abc.com/presentation.pptx";
header("Pragma: public"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
header("Content-Type: ".$ctype); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($file)."\";" ); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file)); 

ob_clean(); 
flush(); 
readfile( $file);
```

How can I get all browsers to reliably download the file instead of displaying the seemingly random behaviour above?

Edit: Below is the code that worked for me, I am not sure what was the problem, unwanted headers or file path ? I made both the changes and it worked.

```
$ctype = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation";
$file = "Presentation3.pptx";
header("Pragma: public"); 
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Content-Type: ".$ctype); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($file)."\";" ); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file)); 
readfile( $file);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: see my answer i think it helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893738/zip-file-downloading-as-php/15893990#15893990

Comment: @vascowhite : question is : file download works different on different browsers

Comment: That isn't a question, it's a statement. Are you looking for an explanation of why this is, or are you looking for code to solve some problem you are having?

Comment: @vascowhite- :) ok, i want to know what i am missing in the code.

Comment: why are you fetching from a full-blown http url? If that file's on your server, why do ANOTHER http request to load it int your script, just to fire it out the door?

Comment: I was trying different variation, so its there, no special reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my test of your code work perfectly if use local file instead url with url give me 0kb too

i test in firefox,IE,Chrome all result is same

```
  // content type for pptx file 
    $ctype = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation";

    $file = "presentation.pptx";//attention  

    header("Pragma: public"); 
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
    header("Content-Type: ".$ctype); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($file)."\";" ); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file)); 

    ob_clean(); 
    flush(); 
    readfile( $file);
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion and Marcelo's suggestion, and its working fine in all browsers. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If file is in your server, don't use URL. If it is an external file, I would write it first to your server, and then print it to user.

I would also delete the `header("Cache-Control: private",false);` line; and use `header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');` instead of `header("Expires: 0");`. It always worked for me this way :)

Also try deleting `ob_clean(); flush();` (as there is nothing to flush or clean before sending the file).

Comment: I followed your suggestion and Mohammads suggestion, and its working fine in all browsers. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please note that there are some issue in IOS browsers for download.

Comment: I tested it on windows 7, Safari 5.1.7, By the ways, what problem did you face in ios browser ?? Thanks

Comment: I tried in safari in ipod,ipad etc. In mac windows etc it works fine.
I tried to add audio download functionality. But instead of download it started streaming.

Comment: Can you pleased do me a favor ? Please try to download pptx and zip ?