# php download function not working

Tags: php, file, download

**Code**

```
public static function download($file, $type = 'application/octet-stream') {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: ' . $type);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        die();
    }
}
```

**Error**
[image: The Error]

Firefox & Chrome both having the same problem

Any help would helpful.

Thank you

Comment: thats some error message...

Comment: can anyone explain me why i got vote down?

Comment: It's not error. It's file content.

Comment: It's a mystery, why people give downvote .

Comment: well i got the problem. i was using `ob_end_flush()` before the download. thats why it was showing the content or error. Thank you for your time guys.

Answer (score 0):

$FilePath is complete full path. Use This, this will help you a lot.

```
download_file($FilePaths);

function download_file( $fullPath )
{
  if( headers_sent() )
    die('Headers Sent');


  if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');


  if( file_exists($fullPath) )
  {

    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

    switch ($ext) 
    {
      case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
      case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
      case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
      case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
      case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
      case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
      case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
      case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
      case "jpeg":
      case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
      default: $ctype="application/force-download";
    }

    header("Pragma: public"); 
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); 
    header("Content-Type: $ctype");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fullPath)."\";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile( $fullPath );

  } 
  else
    die('File Not Found');

}
```

Comment: For more info, check this.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329586/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-php-and-mysql-db/32330239#32330239